# printf doesn't work on specific context, why?

Tags: c, printf, strcmp

I needed to test something and programmed this little bit of code(shown below). I can't understand why the first print works and the second doesn't. The output of this program is just

```
    this prints
```

but it should be

```
    this prints
    this doesn't print i: 1
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(char *str) {
    char *z[1];
    strcpy(*z, "z");
    int a;

    a = strcmp(str, *z);

    return a;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char *name[1];
    printf("this prints\n");

    strcpy(*name, "y");
    i = cmp(*name);
    printf("this doesn't print i:%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *z[1]; // this is an array of pointer
strcpy(*z, "z"); // you have to allocate at least 2 bytes for *z

// and
char *name[1];
strcpy(*name, "y"); // you have to allocate at least 2 bytes for *name also
```

You did not allocate for the pointer in array `z` and `name`.

Your `cmp` function looks weird. If you want to compare string with `"z"`, you can just do:

```
int cmp(char *str){
   return strcmp(str, "z");
}
```

You do not need to use `char *name[1]`, just `char *name = malloc(SIZE+1);` or `char name[SIZE+1]` (`SIZE` is length of string that you want to compare) is enough.

Comment: This answer explains the "why" without just fixing the problem, which is good. What the question exposes is that there's a subtle difference between arrays of characters (fixed sizes) and strings (null terminated) and using pointers (whether they are to an array, static string, or allocated memory). This short resource will fill in the knowledge gap, https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/.

Comment: Your link was really helpful but I thought I should point out that it's written for C++, as it uses the 'new' keyword. According to the Cameron Skinner 'new' is a C++ keyword https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595560/plain-c-using-new-keyword

Comment: @GigiNicaragua, i think he just wants to show you some definition of C string (array of characters, pointer to character). You can ignore  `new` keyword. OT, does my answer solve your problem. If yes, you can click on the check mark ("V") of the answer to accept it

Comment: @Hitokiri Done. Your answer was really helpful aswell, thanks! What does OT mean?

Comment: It means other thing :))

Answer (score 1):

`char *z[1];` and `char *name[]`

1. Both `name` and `z` are not arrays of `char`. They are both an array of one pointer to `char`.
2. Both pointers `name[1]` and `z[1]` point to no valid memory, thus dereferencing it and attempting to store a string to that undefined memory by using `strcpy(*name, "y");` and `strcpy(*z, "z");` and invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). - What you need is an array of `char` for both, `name` and `z`.
3. For storing a string you need one element to store the string-terminating null character.

Use `char z[2]` and `name[2]`, if you only want to have strings contained of one single character.

---

BTW, Your code is a little bit complicate handled. You do not to use strings if you want to store and compare only single characters. It could be simplified as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char name = 'y';
    printf("In name is the character: '%c'\n", name);

    printf("Is the character 'z' in 'name'? %d", name == 'z');
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In name is the character: 'y'
Is the character 'z' in 'name'? 0
```

Where `0` means `false` and `1` signifies `true`.

---

Side Note:

You didn´t need to `#include <stdlib.h>` at any point of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very well written and helpful.